# How can a integer and a character be in same mathematical expression?

Tags: java, integer, character

I was studying a book and I found this :

```
int tiles = ch - 'A';
```

where `ch` is a character.

What I dont understand is how did operating between two characters result an integer?

Comment: Through binary numeric promotion. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `char` variable is actually stored in memory as a numeric value. That number represents a specific character (`a`, `b`, `é`, ...), according to a specific codification (usually the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/)).

For instance:

```
Decimal    Char
----------------
65         A
66         B
...        ...
```

You can use a `char` variable as if it was a numeric variable. It will be automatically cast and will have the numeric value representing the `char`. And viceversa, a numeric value can be interpreted as a `char`.

```
// The ASCII code for 65 is A
int result = 100 - 'A';
System.out.println ("100 - A is " + result); // Prints 35

System.out.println("ASCII code for 65: " + (char)65); // Prints A
```

Here's a [**Ideone demo**](http://ideone.com/h2F8o0) of the code above.

Getting into detail, according to the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), sections [5.6.2. Binary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2), and [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) :

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening
>   primitive conversions:
>
> - ...
> - char to int, long, float, or double
> - ...

Comment: I think this is a bit dense for a beginner to understand.  Maybe it could be expanded a bit?

Comment: So if ch = 'B', then what would be the value of tile?

Comment: It would be 66 because that is the ASCII value for 'B'.

Comment: `char`s interpreted as numbers take their values from the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). `B` is the value `66`.

Comment: oh, ok so conversion of char to int automatically replaces it with its ASCII code. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As you can read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has
> a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or
> 65,535 inclusive).

So we can see, that internally a char is stored as a numeric value. And, as you can read [here](http://www.particle.kth.se/%7Elindsey/JavaCourse/Book/Part1/Java/Chapter02/operators.html)

> char, when in numeric operations is treated as an unsigned two byte
> integer

Also, in the [oracle docs about conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2), we can see that char to int is one of the Widening Primitive Conversion, along with:

- byte to short, int, long, float, or double
- short to int, long, float, or double
- char to int, long, float, or double
- int to long, float, or double
- long to float or double
- float to double

and, [more references](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/15-200/lectures/voe/lecture.html#ImplicitConversion):

> Java will automatically convert a char value into an int value (and
> vice-versa) if necessary.
>
> Java performs one other implicit conversion when necessary: a char is
> implicitly converted to an int (according to its value in the ASCII
> table). So in 'A'+1, the char 'A' is first implicitly converted to the
> int 65 so that it can be added to the int 1 finally producing an int
> result of 66. In fact, in the expression 1.5+'A', 'A' is first
> implicitly converted to the int 65 and then implicitly converted to
> the double 65. finally producing an double 66.5 as a result.
>
> Finally, the expression '5'-'0' implicitly converts both char values
> to int (53 and 48 respectively: see the ASCII table) and then performs
> subtraction: the result in this case is the int 5. In fact, if we
> declare char d = '8'; (or any other character that is a digit), then
> writing d-'0' results in an int equivalent to the digit (in this case
> 8). Note that the ASCII value of '8' is 56 and of '0' is 48.

Answer (score 1):

Every character has an ascii value (an integer). In other words, every character has a number that represents it. Doing the operation 'ch - A' will yield you with a number between 0 and 26, assumming 'ch' is between A and Z.